# Find the distance between a function and a subspace in $L^2(0,\pi)$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Find a distance from vector $h(t)=t$ to the subspace 
>   $$M=\left\{x(t)\in L^2(0,\pi):\int_o^{\pi}x(t)\cos t \, dt=0\right\}.$$

So, it's a basic exercise, but I'm a bit confused solving that. Can someone explain how to do it? I know that by definition
 $$\operatorname{dist}(h,M)=\inf\|t-x(t)\|,$$ 
but this is a conditional extremum problem. Can I solve it using Fourier coefficients, we know that any function in a Hilbert space we can approximate of linear combination of basic elements?

I hope that someone explain how to find a distance using  the last way or may be there are exist more faster ways.

Comment: Can you express $M$ as a hyperplane?

Comment: How is ||t-x(t)|| defined?

Comment: @Acccumulation How defined norm or this expression?

Comment: @copper.hat It's a sum $x_i(t)$ such that $\int_o^{\pi}x_i(t)costdt=0$? Actually I'm noe quite understand how to do it

Comment: Huh??? How about writing $M= \{x | \langle \cos, x \rangle = 0 \}$? Then think of Pythagoras (in a mathematical way).

Comment: @copper.hat Oh, sorry, of course that is

Comment: For me, it always helps to try and draw a little picture/diagram of the problem.

Comment: @copper.hat for any 2 vectors we can find a angle between them and write this angle through $\cos$, right?

Comment: How is the norm defined? Is it L2?

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes, it's default norm in $L_2$. In this case $||x||=\sqrt{\int_0^{\pi}x^2dt}$

Comment: @copper.hat $<\cos,x>=0$ It means that are orthogonal, but in $L_2$ exist functions, except $\sin$ and $1$, which are  orthogonal to $\cos$?

Comment: Try thinking in finite dimensions first. What are the characteristics of the nearest point in a plane to a given point?

Comment: @copper.hat I did not quite understand your question, can you explain what means "characteristics of the nearest point in a plane to a given point"

Comment: If I have a plane with normal $n$ and some point $x$, then if the nearest point in the plane to $x$ is $p$, then $x-p$ must lie along the normal $n$ and hence is perpendicular to the plane.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, I know it, I just misunderstood the question

Answer (score 2):

Start by writing
$$
                  x = \left[x-\frac{\langle x,\cos\rangle}{\langle \cos,\cos\rangle}\cos\right]+\frac{\langle x,\cos\rangle}{\langle \cos,\cos\rangle}\cos.
$$
$M$ consists of everything orthogonal to $\cos$, which includes the first term on the right. And the second term is orthogonal to $M$. So the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$ is the first term, which must also be the closest point in $M$ to $x$. So, the distance from $x$ to $M$ is
\begin{align}
      \left\|x-\left[x-\frac{\langle x,\cos\rangle}{\langle\cos,\cos\rangle}\cos\right]\right\| & =\left\|\frac{\langle x,\cos\rangle}{\langle\cos,\cos\rangle}\cos\right\| \\
    & = \frac{|\langle x,\cos\rangle|}{\|\cos\|} \\
    & =\frac{\left|\int_{0}^{\pi}x\cos(x)dx\right|}{\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^2xdx\right)^{1/2}}.
\end{align}

Comment: So, how would I find the distance between x and M (orthogonal), essential space spanned by cos(x)

Comment: @benhuni : If you decompose $x=x_{M}+x_{M^{\perp}}$, where $x_{M}\in M$ and $x_{M^{\perp}}\in M^{\perp}$, then the distance from $x$ to $M$ is $\|x-x_{M}\|$. In your case $x_{M}=x-\frac{\langle x,\cos x\rangle}{\langle \cos x,\cos x\rangle}$ and $x_{M^{\perp}}=\frac{\langle x,\cos x\rangle}{\langle \cos x,\cos x\rangle}\cos x$.

Comment: Ohh this is much clearer now, thanks. So, essentially we are looking to decompose x into M and $M^\perp$, then distance is easy to find,
Last question, why it important to make the component orthonormal.  Would $x = (x-<x,\cos x>\cos x)+<x,\cos x> \cos x $ suffice?

Comment: @benhuni : You need a right triangle in order to use the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: I believe in inner product spaces for Pythag thm you only need orthogonality.

Comment: @benhuni : Did you check whether or not you actually have orthogonality? Try, and let me know. What about $\langle x-\langle x,\cos x\rangle \cos x,\langle x,\cos x\rangle \cos x\rangle$??? Is it $0$?

Comment: Ahh, I see thanks a lot. Yes, being orthonormal is needed!
I have a exam tomorrow this is what I needed! :)

Comment: @benhuni : Good timing, then. :) Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you represent y(t) as x(t)+f(t), where x(t) is in M. Then the distance from y(t) to x(t) is f * f (note: I’m ignoring the square root because it’s irrelevant for optimization purposes). Setting the derivative to zero, 2f * df = 0. If y(t) is fixed and x(t) can vary, then x(t) can vary only within M, and thus dx is in M. Since f = y-x, and y is fixed, df = -dx, and thus df is in M as well. So f is a vector such that f*(elements of M) = 0. Intuitively, the distance from a point to a surface is the length of the normal vector from the surface to the point (a normal vector from the surface to the point is not in general unique, but with a hyperplane it is).

You are already given that cos(t) * (every element of M) = 0. With a little hand waving, it follows that f = a cos(t) for some scalar a, and so the distance from y to M is a*length of cos(t). a  is y * cos/(cos*cos), so the distance is y * cos/||cos||.

Comment: You need to use MathJax.